# In Ember, how to defer readiness, and put AJAX result into a Controller?

Tags: ember.js, promise

I understand that Ember.Application now has [deferReadiness](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_deferReadiness) that lets me wait for the return of an AJAX call before initializing the app.  However, in the example in the api docs, they put the value into a global variable in the App:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.deferReadiness();

jQuery.getJSON("/auth-token", function(token) {
  App.token = token;
  App.advanceReadiness();
});
```

Rather than introducing a global variable for the token, I want to place the returned value into my ApplicationController.  However, I can't seem to find how to get a handle to a controller at this point, i.e. in the jQuery callback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [`reopen`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_reopen) your controller in the `$.getJSON` callback to set the response value in the `token` property. Assuming you have an endpoint `~/auth-token` returning a JSON with a single attribute `key`, you can do something like this:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
    token: ''
});

App.deferReadiness();

$.getJSON("/auth-token", function(token) {
    console.log(token.key);
    App.ApplicationController.reopen({
        token: token.key
    });
    App.advanceReadiness();
});
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/NPaaA/))

Comment: I just knew there would be a way!