# Loading state for ApplicationRoute

Tags: ember.js

Using: ember 1.7.0

I have some server-side data that I want to load up in my ember app before any routes are transitioned to.  Multiple (but not all) of my other routes / controllers need this data.  I was thinking that I could just load up this data in the ApplicationRoute `model` method.  It works fine, but does not display a loading state.

Is it possible to have the ApplicationRoute display a loading state until it's `model` promise gets resolved.

Here's a jsbin illustrating the problem: http://jsbin.com/soqivo/1/

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was playing around with [this](http://jsbin.com/reyuti/5/edit?html,js,output) the other day, might help you out. This sample is kind of buggy because it was written by me lol, but written properly this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the sample.  Same issue though - when I add a wait to the ApplicationRoute `model` it just shows a white screen.  http://jsbin.com/titoz/1/

Comment: Have a look at it http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

As of [1.11.0 release](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_named-substates), it should be possible to define a *loading* substate for the application route.

### TL;DR;

I think this is by design, but not a design flaw. This particular issue is happening because that long model request is taking place in `ApplicationRoute#model` when it should be in `IndexRoute#model`. Move that promise/request into the index route and it should be fine. If you must add stuff to the application controller, consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205615/in-ember-how-to-defer-readiness-and-put-ajax-result-into-a-controller/16254735#16254735), combined with something that says "loading" in your index.html file while the app is waiting.

### Why

`Ember.Route` has a number of hooks that we often override so it does what we want instead of a default implementation. The most obvious hook being `model` and `setupController`. But sometimes we simply don't write the `setuptController` method because it does what we want it to do already (given one just wants to set the `model` into the `controller`). But regardless of these methods being overridden, they will run as part of an internal workflow anyway. This workflow has a number of steps that are not often discussed because *they already do what we want* and we tend to forget about them and their importance, and, as for this particular issue, the order in which these methods get called in the route life cycle.

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.logs = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
  content: []
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {});
});

function loggingAlias(property) {
  return function() {
    App.logs.pushObject(this._debugContainerKey + ' ' + property);
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

App.LoggingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  enter: loggingAlias('enter (private)'),
  exit: loggingAlias('exit (private)'),
  activate: loggingAlias('activate'),
  deactivate: loggingAlias('deactivate'),
  serialize: loggingAlias('serialize'),
  deserialize: loggingAlias('deserialize (private)'),
  model: loggingAlias('model'),
  setupController: loggingAlias('setupController'),
  afterModel: loggingAlias('afterModel'),
  beforeModel: loggingAlias('beforeModel'),
  renderTemplate: loggingAlias('renderTemplate'),
  redirect: loggingAlias('redirect')
});

App.LogsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: App.logs,
  actions: {
    clearLogs: function() {
      App.logs.clear();
    }
  }
});

App.ApplicationRoute = App.LoggingRoute.extend();
App.PostsRoute = App.LoggingRoute.extend();
App.PostsIndexRoute = App.LoggingRoute.extend();
```

```css
/* Put your CSS here */

html,
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Ember Route Hook Order" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Route Hook Order</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">

    <strong>Note:</strong>  <em>
    MilkyWayJoe says: I didn't write this. I have found in jsbin at: <a href="http://jsbin.com/rolo/2/edit?output">http://jsbin.com/rolo/2/edit?output</a>
    <br /> 
    Added here in case the link goes kaput just to point out the order of Ember.Route internal workflow steps 
    </em>
    <br />
    <br />{{link-to 'Index' 'index'}} {{link-to 'Posts' 'posts'}} {{outlet}} {{render 'logs'}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" id='logs'>
    <h3>Logged Method Calls</h3>

    <a href="#" {{action 'clearLogs'}}>Clear Logs</a>
    <ul>
      {{#each}}
      <li>{{this}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Since `renderTemplate` is the **last** to get called so it only makes sense that it doesn't render anything until the promise(s) within a given route get resolved.

For child routes, that's totally fine because their `loading` substate will have some type of *canvas* to draw onto, since a parent-already-loaded-living-and-breathing-route has been loaded prior this route even being instantiated. But that's not true for the `ApplicationRoute` since it has no parent route or template to rely upon, thus rendering a blank page until all promises get resolved.

#### Working snippet

The next best thing is moving any long running requests to a child route. As the proposed solution, I've moved your 3 sec promise to `IndexRoute#model` since this route will run *anyway* and is the direct child of `ApplicationRoute` by default. I would say reserve the application route or controller for handling `error` events instead.

```js
App = Em.Application.create({
  displayName: 'Test.App'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('files', function() {
    this.route('index', {path: '/'});
    this.resource('file', { path: ':file_id' }, function() {
      this.route('index', {path: '/'});
      this.route('detail');
    });
  });
});

App.FilesController = Em.ArrayController.extend();
App.FilesFileController = Em.ObjectController.extend();

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({}); 

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params, transition){
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
        Ember.run.later(function(){ 
          var model =  App.Person.create();
          resolve(model);
        }, 3000); 
      });
    } 
});

App.LoadingRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('loading', {
      into: 'application',
      outlet: 'loading'
    });
  }
});

App.FileLoadingRoute = App.LoadingRoute.extend();
 
App.FilesRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var selfie = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
        Ember.run.later(function() {  
            var model = selfie.store.find('file');
            resolve(model);
        }, 800);  
    });
  }
});

App.FilesIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.all('file');
  }
});

App.FileRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) { 
    return this.store.find('file', params.file_id);
  } 
});

App.FileIndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {  
    return this.modelFor('file');  
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    
    this.render('files/index', {
      into: 'application'
    });
    
    this.render('file/index', {
      into: 'files/index',
      outlet: 'file'
    });
    
  }
});

App.FileDetailRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var selfie = this;
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
        Ember.run.later(function(){ 
            var file = selfie.modelFor('file');
            var model = selfie.store.find('fileDetail', file.id);
            resolve(model);
        }, 800);  
    });
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    
    this.render('files/index', {
      into: 'application'
    });
    
    this.render('file/index', {
      into: 'files/index',
      outlet: 'file'
    });
    
    this.render('file/detail', {
      into: 'file/index',
      outlet: 'detail'
    });
  },
  actions: {
    loading: function() {
      return true;
    }
  }
});

App.RlLoadIndicatorComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  
  classNames: ['rl-load-indicator'],
  classNameBindings: ['isLoading:rl-overlay:rl-silent'],
  overlay: true,
  spinner: true,
  message: 'Loading...',
  loading: false,
  
  isLoading: function() {
    return this.get('loading');
  }.property('loading'),
  
  spinnerClass: function() {
    if (this.get('loading')) {
      if (this.get('spinner')) {
        return 'rl-spinner';
      }
    }
    return "";
  }.property(),
  
  actions: {
    setLoading: function() {
      this.set('loading', true);
    },
    setDone: function() {
      this.set('loading', false);
    }
  }
  
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.File = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'), 
  text: DS.attr('string'),
  detail: DS.belongsTo('fileDetail', {async: true})
});

App.FileDetail = DS.Model.extend({
  owner: DS.attr('string'),
  canEdit: DS.attr('bool'),
  file: DS.belongsTo('file'),
  property1: DS.attr('string'),
  property2: DS.attr('string'),
  property3: DS.attr('string'),
  property4: DS.attr('string'),
  property5: DS.attr('string')
});

App.File.FIXTURES = [
  {id: 1, name: 'File 1', text: 'Blah 1', detail: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'File 2', text: 'Blah 2', detail: 2},
  {id: 3, name: 'File 3', text: 'Blah 3', detail: 3},
  {id: 4, name: 'File 4', text: 'Blah 4', detail: 4},
  {id: 5, name: 'File 5', text: 'Blah 5', detail: 5},
  {id: 6, name: 'File 6', text: 'Blah 6', detail: 6},
  {id: 7, name: 'File 7', text: 'Blah 7', detail: 7},
  {id: 8, name: 'File 8', text: 'Blah 8', detail: 8},
  {id: 9, name: 'File 9', text: 'Blah 9', detail: 9},
  {id: 10, name: 'File 10', text: 'Blah 10', detail: 10}
];

App.FileDetail.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1, 
    owner: 'Spiderman', 
    canEdit: true, 
    file_id: 1, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'With great values, comes great bindings'
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    owner: 'Iron Man', 
    canEdit: true, 
    file_id: 2, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'Another Value'
  },
  {
    id: 3, 
    owner: 'Thor', 
    canEdit: false, 
    file_id: 3, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'Another Value'
  },
  {
    id: 4, 
    owner: 'Captain America', 
    canEdit: false, 
    file_id: 4, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'Another Value'
  },
  {
    id: 5, 
    owner: 'Neil DeGrasse Tyson', 
    canEdit: true, 
    file_id: 5, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'Another Value'
  },
  {
    id: 6, 
    owner: 'Dr. Doom', 
    canEdit: false, 
    file_id: 6, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'Another Value'
  },
  {
    id: 7, 
    owner: 'Reed Richards', 
    canEdit: true, 
    file_id: 7, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'Another Value'
  },
  {
    id: 8, 
    owner: 'Walter White', 
    canEdit: true, 
    file_id: 8, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'Say My Name!' 
  },
  {
    id: 9, 
    owner: 'Jesse Pinkmann', 
    canEdit: true, 
    file_id: 9, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'Bitch'
  },
  {
    id: 10, 
    owner: 'Hawk Barton', 
    canEdit: false, 
    file_id: 10, 
    property1: 'Value 1', 
    property2: 'Value 2', 
    property3: 'Value 3', 
    property4: 'Value 4', 
    property5: 'Another Value' 
  }
];
```

```css
/* Put your CSS here */
html, body {
  margin: 20px;
}

.rl-load-indicator {
  text-align: center;
}

.rl-overlay {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    background: url(data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdwnLpRPAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAUGFpbnQuTkVUIHYzLjUuNUmK/OAAAAATSURBVBhXY2RgYNgHxGAAYuwDAA78AjwwRoQYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat scroll transparent\9; /* ie fallback png background image */
    z-index:9999;
    color:white;
}

.rl-silent {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.rl-spinner {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #27ae60;
  margin: 100px auto;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  -webkit-animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.arrow-right {
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-top: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
 border-left: 5px solid green;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateplane {
  0% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) }
  50% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) }
  100% { -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)  rotateX(180deg) }
}

@keyframes rotateplane {
  0% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 50% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg) 
  } 100% { 
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Loading Thingy" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.7.0/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>{{unbound App.displayName}}</h1>
    {{partial "menu"}}
    <hr />
    {{outlet}} 
    {{outlet "loading"}} 
  </script>
 
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="loading">
  {{rl-load-indicator loading=true}}
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_menu">
{{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}} |    {{#link-to 'files.index'}}Files{{/link-to}}
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h3>Index</h3>
    Content goes here
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="files/index">
    <h3>Files</h3>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {{#each file in model}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{file.id}}</td>
          <td>{{file.name}}</td>
          <td>
            {{#link-to 'file.index' file}}
            <p class="arrow-right"></p>
            {{/link-to}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    {{outlet "file"}} 
  </script>
  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="file/index">
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    {{text}}
    <hr />{{#link-to 'file.detail'}}Detail{{/link-to}}
    {{outlet "detail"}}
    
  </script>
  
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="file/detail">
    <h5>Details</h5>
    <hr />
    <ul>
    <li>owner: {{owner}}</li>
    <li>can edit: {{canEdit}}</li>
    <li>property 1: {{property1}}</li>
    <li>property 2: {{property3}}</li>
    <li>property 3: {{property3}}</li>
    <li>property 4: {{property4}}</li>
    <li>property 5: {{property5}}</li>
    </script>
  
  
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/rl-load-indicator">
  <div {{bind-attr class=spinnerClass}}></div>
  {{unbound message}}
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the background on "why" this is by design when it comes to the ApplicationRoute.  I think I'll probably take your suggestion of having some base html (outside of ember) which has the initial loading state.  The reason I don't want to stuff this into the IndexRoute (or any other route), is because I want to make sure it always happens.  If someone were to deep link into my app for a specific route they would then bypass the IndexRoute.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a different resource below the application route, and do all of your loading there.  Don't use the index route though, it is only hit when you hit the root of a particular resource (App.IndexRoute would be when you just hit the root of your application).

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("top",function(){ // a place you can grab things for the app and block
    this.resource('home');  // a place you want to get when everything is ready
  });
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo("home");
  }
});
App.TopRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
//   This does trigger a loading state
  model: function(params){
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            resolve();
        }, 3000); // 3 second delay, wooh, your server is slow!!!
    });
  }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/mivul/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I use any route other than the ApplicationRoute, the pre-loading of data would be bypassed if a user deep linked directly into some other route in my app?  Maybe what I need is to just have all of my routes that need this pre-loaded data, inherit from some base class.

Comment: Incorrect :) if they hit a resource anywhere deeper in the top resource it will always resolve the top model before moving on to the next deeper resource.