# RESTAdapter not working with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am working with Ember and attempting to retrieve data from my REST API, but it is not working as intended. First of all i am quite unsure how to debug RESTAdapters and second of all i don't see the call being made in the Chrome Devtools Network view.

HTML:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-data.js/1.0.0-beta.11/ember-data.js"></script>
```

Here is my JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
        host: 'http://example.com/api'
    })
});

App.Bodypart = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Bodypart.find();
    }
});
```

My console returns:

```
Error while processing route: index undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I understand this means that i obviously am returning some null pointer or a empty model.

So the question arrises, how do i debug the RESTAdapter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using an old ember-data syntax and applying it to 1.0beta11. I don't have a link at the moment, but check on the official repository or the guides. The `model` hook in your route should change from:

```
return App.Bodypart.find();
```

to

```
return this.store.find('bodypart');
```

Also you seem to be declaring your adapter incorrectly as well. It should be:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://example.com',
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

Also, consider changing the request from the `ApplicationRoute` to a child route, or you *may* experience "fake frozen" application as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536604/loading-state-for-applicationroute)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working, but i think theres a problem with the JSON response from my API, as it returns like this `[{"id":1,"name":"Something"},{"id":2,"name":"Something else"}]`  which does not incorporate the `Bodypart` variable. The error i get now is: `Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined Error: Assertion Failed: The response from a findAll must be an Array, not undefined`

Comment: your json should be `{bodyparts: [{...}, {...}]}`. Note that the root container has to be in the plural for arrays and singular for single item: `{bodypart: {...} }`

Comment: Makes pretty good sense. Thanks for the tip concerning the router, i will get that fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding debugging Ember, checking the tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info
shows the following link: 
[Debugging Ember](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/debugging/)

That may help.